# How to add a clear button in `mat-datepicker`

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to add a clear button in `mat-datepicker`. Exactly in the open calendar how to add a date cleaning button.

```html
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="data1" [matDatepicker]="data1" [value]="" formControlName="data1" id="data1" name="data1">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="data1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #data1></mat-datepicker>
```

I put inside the attribute:

```html
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="data1" [matDatepicker]="data1" [value]="" formControlName="data1" id="data1" name="data1">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="data1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #data1>
    <button (click)="onClickMe()">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-datepicker>
```

but it doesn't work.

I would ask for help. Thank you.

Answer (score 35):

This solution uses the existing functionality of `mat-datepicker-toggle` without tying it to the `datePicker` using the `for` binding, which makes it do nothing instead of toggling the visibility of the calendar.

Adding a `click` binding allows arbitrary code to execute, in this case, calling the `clear` function in the component's JS/TS.

The icon on `mat-datepicker-toggle` can be customized by adding a child `mat-icon` component with a `matDatepickerToggleIcon` directive.  This replaces the calendar icon with an arbitrary icon, in this case, the clear icon. [source](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

By default, the icons are stacked vertically.  This is fixed by making `mat-datepicker-toggle` display as `inline-block` with CSS.

[Screenshot of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SqxC.png)

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker" [(ngModel)]="startDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix (click)="clearStartDate()">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>clear</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component.ts

```ts
startDate: Date;

clearStartDate() {
    this.startDate = null;
}
```

CSS

```css
mat-datepicker-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The icon works perfectly, but the transpiler is throwing an error:
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

Answer (score 1):

The `mat-datepicker` does not have an option to add a clear icon to the input by default. But we can get this in our datepicker by playing around with the `css` of the `mat-icon` button and the `input`. We need to place our `mat-icon` after the `input` in our HTML.

I would also suggest against using `ngModel` and `formControlName` on the same element. Use one or the other. You are also using `data1` as your `ngModel` when you have a template variable with the same name. Just change the `ngModel` to another unique variable.

We now have the clear icon in our `mat-datepicker`, but there's another problem, when you click the clear icon, the datepicker input comes into focus. To prevent the `click` event from bubbling up the DOM tree, we need to use `event.stopPropagation()`

Change your HTML like below

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input class="mat-datepicker-input" matInput [(ngModel)]="date" [matDatepicker]="data1" id="data1" name="data1">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon (click)="clearDate($event)">clear</mat-icon>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="data1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #data1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your css

```css
.mat-datepicker-input {
    width: 85%;
}

mat-icon {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

In your component

```
clearDate(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.date = null;
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-clear-input).

Comment: Thank you. Can you put my buttons instead of `previousClicked ('year')` `nextClicked('year')` Just like example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gkalnnqebag?file=app%2Fdatepicker-custom-header-example.ts